# Fixing libtool for -rpath problems

Tags: bitcoin-core, server, daemon, compiling

I am trying compile bitcoin on Debian 7 Wheezy (64bit) but I am encountering the error `Fixing libtool for -rpath problems.`

I installed all dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool autotools-dev autoconf pkg-config libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install libdb4.8-dev libdb4.8++-dev (like that http://askubuntu.com/questions/290094/libdb4-8-is-no-longer-available
apt-get install miniupnpc

$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
...
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating libsecp256k1.pc
config.status: creating src/libsecp256k1-config.h
config.status: src/libsecp256k1-config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
Fixing libtool for -rpath problems.
```

What is the solution to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error.

Continue by running make, optimally with `-j` set to the number of cores you have on your system.